# Is this generalization of Dunford-Pettis theorem correct?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $ (X, \mathcal{F}, \mu) $ be a measure space. We do not make any assumption on $\mu$. It can fail to be $\sigma$-finite, for example.

Let $\Phi$ be a subset of $L^1(\mu)$. We call $\Phi$ **uniformly integrable** if for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $M > 0$ such that
$$\sup_{f \in \Phi} \int_{|f| \geq M} |f| d\mu < \epsilon $$
We call $\Phi$ **tight** if for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a measurable set $X_0 \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\mu(X_0) < \infty$ and
$$\sup_{f \in \Phi} \int_{X \setminus X_0} |f| d\mu < \epsilon $$

I have read the following generalization of Dunford-Pettis theorem somewhere:

> **Claim**
>
> Let $ (X, \mathcal{F}, \mu) $ be a measure space and $\Phi$ be a
> subset of $L^1(\mu)$. Then the followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\Phi$ is uniformly integrable and tight
> 2. $\Phi$ is relatively compact in the weak topology
> 3. Every sequence in $\Phi$ has a weakly convergent subsequence

Is the above claim correct? It seems hard to believe given that $\mu$ is not even $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: what is the generalization you are taking about? perhaps you should state that precise result.

Comment: I'm not that worried by the lack of $\sigma$-finiteness because, if I'm not mistaken, if $\Phi$ is tight then there is a $\sigma$-finite set $Y$ such that all $f \in \Phi$ vanish a.e. outside $Y$.  So we might as well replace $X$ by $Y$ and then we have a $\sigma$-finite measure.  I suspect that the other two statements will imply the same thing, so there'd be no loss of generality in assuming $\mu$ $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz I have made it a claim explicitly

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Oh, indeed. I haven't thought of that. That's why  assumption of $\sigma$-finiteness is not needed.